# How to map cw to ciw in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I almost never use the `cw` in Vim. Instead I use `ciw`. Is there a way to make `cw` do the same thing as `ciw`? I have tried googling and looking in the man page but I have not found a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very straightforward mapping. Type

```
:nnoremap cw ciw
```

or if you'd like it to always apply, add this line somewhere in your `.vimrc` file *without* the colon at the beginning. In general, if you'd like to make `foo` do the same thing as `bar`, you can just run

```
:nnoremap foo bar
```

and then typing `foo` will do *exactly* the same thing as if you had typed `bar`. There are some more nuances than that, like using `nnoremap` vs `nmap`, and the various modes to use. However, mapping `cw` to `ciw` is pretty basic stuff, so, I'd highly recommend just reading through [`:h map.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html)

Comment: Thanks! answered my question and game me more reading to expand my knowledge.